# How to emit data with socket.io client-side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I am using socket.io to transmit data real-time between a server and a client.

I am able to establish the connection between the server and the client , and the server is able to emit a socket client ID just fine.

But I am unable to emit data from the client to the server. My goal is to make the client sending data to the server to further processing but I think there is something I am doing wrong , and I can't figure out what.

Server.js here ...

```
var ioJSON = require('./io');
var serverPort = ioJSON.server.port;
var date = new Date();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serverPort);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected at '+date+' with socket ID: '+ socket.client.id);
    io.emit('socketClientID', socket.client.id);
});
```

and client.js here ...

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/", {
    reconnection: true
});


socket.on('socketClientID', function (socketClientID) {
    console.log('Connection to server established. SocketID is',socketClientID);
});
```

My goal is to send data from the client to the server. I will greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `socket.emit(eventName, args)` to send data in the client as such:

client.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/", {
    reconnection: true
});

socket.on('socketClientID', function (socketClientID) {
    console.log('Connection to server established. SocketID is',socketClientID);
    socket.emit('hello_from_client', 123);
});
```

And in the sever listen to the event with `socket.on(eventName, callback)`

server.js:

```
var ioJSON = require('./io');
var serverPort = ioJSON.server.port;
var date = new Date();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serverPort);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected at '+date+' with socket ID: '+ socket.client.id);
    io.emit('socketClientID', socket.client.id);
    socket.on('hello_from_client', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```